# How do I hide a column in an Angular Material table when that entire column is null in the datasource?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material table with the columns :
tablecolumns: string[] = ["mbrID", "E", "B", "HasAccess", "Att", "select"];

The information that I receive can be of two types. Type A has all the columns filled. For type B, columns E and B will always be null. From the response that I get from the service with which I populate the datsource, I can't find out whether the info is of type A or type B. How can I check whether the value of those particular columns in datasource is null and hide them in display?

This is my Angular code for filling the datasource.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.Service.ObservableName.subscribe(
      (response: Recipient[]) => {
        this.RcptData = response;
        console.log(this.RcptData);
        this.tabledata = new MatTableDataSource(response);
      }
    )
  }
```

The interface Recipient looks like this:

```js
export interface Recipient {
    mbrId: string,
    E: string,
    B: string,
    hasAccess: string,
    att: string[]
}
```

This is what I have in my HTML code for the table. I have added just for two columns but it's similar for the rest. :

```html
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]='RcptData' class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="mbrID">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Member ID</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let member"> {{member.mbrId}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="E">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>E</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let member"> {{member.E}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tablecolumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row;columns: tablecolumns;"></tr>

</table>
```

Right now, the columns E and B will be visible regardless of the type of data but I want to hide it. Since I don't get what is the type of data from the backend service, I can't figure out how to do it. The value of columns E and B will always be null (entire column) for type B. Can I use this somehow to hide columns?